# repetir un numero n veces

Tags: javascript, ng-repeat, slice

Esto es lo que llevo del código, pero no entiendo que tengo mal en el codigo.

```
function fakeBinary(size) {
  // La funcion llamada 'fakeBinary' recibe como argumento size(tamaño) que es un numero (entero)
  // y debe devolver un string de 1s y 0s con el tamaño indicado.
  // siempre empieza por 1
  // Por ej:
  // fakeBinary(10) devuelve "1010101010"
  // fakeBinary(3) devuelve "101"
  // Tu código aca:

     var array = [];
      size.map().forEach(element =>{
        if(element == size.repeat(n)){
          array.push(1);
        }else{
          array.push(0);
        }
      });
    return array.slice(1);
    }
```

Comment: size no es un array, es un número tan solo. ¿que pretendes usando map con el?

Comment: Lo puedes solucionar fácilmente con un bucle for y en el condicional compruebas si es divisible por 2, y te dará el resultado esperado por el enunciado

Comment: Y olvídate de los arrays para solucionar esto, concatena strings y retorna el resultado de la concatenación.

Comment: Tampoco se entiende lo del título. No parece que tenga nada que ver con el ejercicio que te han mandado hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo porque lo metes en un array.
Con solo concatenar en un string ya deberias sacar ese problema.

Puedes hacerlo asi

```js
function fakeBinary(size) {
  let strFakeBinary = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    strFakeBinary += i % 2 == 0 ? '1' : '0';
  }
  return strFakeBinary;
}
console.log(fakeBinary(10))
console.log(fakeBinary(3))
```

Comment: Una de dos, o el que pregunta no se mira la consola (su script tiene fallos de sintaxis descomunales) o bien ha puesto un corta/pega de otros lugares para poder hacer la pregunta (porque... ¿que es **n**? ¿que pinta un foreach despues de un map? ¿porque devuelve un array?  ¿ porque quita un elemento del array que pretende devolver? ... En fin, por eso no le di la respuesta aunque se la sugerí en los comentarios para que lo intentara el.